# How to make two select statement as two columns in postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

It's simple yet I am not able to find it.

I have three tables as follows

```
select * from student;

 id1 | name1  
 ----+--------
   1 | ishi 
   2 | sangee


select * from domain;

 id2 | name2  
-----+--------
   1 | python
   2 | scala
   3 | java
   4 | c#

select * from mainpk;

 id1 | id2 
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   1 |   2
   1 |   3
   2 |   3
   2 |   4
```

I have two select statement:

```
select student.name1 from student join mainpk on student.id1 = mainpk.id1;
```

it results:

```
 name1  
--------
 ishi
 ishi
 ishi
 sangee
 sangee

select domain.name2 from domain join mainpk on domain.id2 = mainpk.id2;`**
```

it results:

```
 name2  
--------
 python
 scala
 java
 java
 c#
```

How to merge these two columns as a single table. Any advice is acceptable.

The expected ouput is:

```
name1  | name2 
-------+-------
ishi   | python  
ishi   | scala  
ishi   | java  
sangee | java
sangee | c#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JOIN` with `mainpk` table result the output, the following query will return the expected result:

```
select st.name1, dm.name2
from mainpk ms
join student st on st.id1 = ms.id1 
join domain dm on dm.id2 = ms.id2
```

Please find the [**working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0001435c6cf9b8215b689e17135274b)