# How to combine two column with colon ":" in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I have a table as follows

```
name1  | name2 
-------+--------
ishi   | python  
ishi   | scala  
ishi   | java  
sangee | java
sangee | c#
```

I need a output as

```
   name   
----------------
ishi   : python  
ishi   : scala  
ishi   : java  
sangee : java
sangee : c#
```

How to join two column as one concatenated with colon `:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With follow up of your [previous question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950248/2451726), using [`CONCAT()`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-concat-function/) function will give the expected result:

```
select CONCAT(st.name1, ' : ', dm.name2) AS name
from mainpk ms
join student st on st.id1 = ms.id1 
join domain dm on dm.id2 = ms.id2
```

or using the string concatenation operator `||`

```
select st.name1 || ' : ' || dm.name2 AS name
....
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat_ws()` for that:

```
select concat_ws(' : ', name1, name2) as name
from the_table;
```

`concat_ws()` will properly deal with NULL values and empty strings (unlike e.g. `name1||' : '||name2`)